# Process and exitcode

Tags: java, batch-file, process, exe, processbuilder

I want to run a exe program from my Java application.I try this code for it.
I run the batch file and batch file runs the exe.

```
try {    
    String command = "C:\\tryfile\\Runprogram.bat";
    //  ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", command);
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command);
    pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
    Process p = pb.start();

    InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
    String line;

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }

    int excode = p.waitFor();
    System.out.println(excode + " asfasf");

    p.destroy();    
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The exe runs well and does what I want.(It insert from csv file to database with bcp).There is no problem about it.

But waitfor method returns 2147483647.
What is it?I have no idea about it.I know that if the exe run and finish without any error it returns 0 normally.But my exe returns 2147483647.

Any idea?

My bat file is here:

C:\tryfile\myprogram.exe

Comment: Is your batch file specifying the exit value?

Comment: No it only runs the exe.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the exit code of the BAT, not the return code of the EXE. But you have not specified an exit code in your BAT so you get trash.

I don't have a windows box on hand but something like this should work

```
C:\tryfile\myprogram.exe
EXIT /B %ERRORLEVEL%
```

Check [Batch files - Errorlevels](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/errorlevel.php)